# Query regarding the file Mage.php

Tags: singleton

I need to understand what the code below actually does? I found this in **Mage.php**

```
 public static function getSingleton($modelClass='', array $arguments=array())
{
    $registryKey = '_singleton/'.$modelClass;
    if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
        self::register($registryKey, self::getModel($modelClass, $arguments));
    }
    return self::registry($registryKey);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The code you mentioned is the implementation of the [Singleton Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for Magento.
This insures that you get the same instance of a class every time you call it, during one of the requests.
Well...this is not actually the singleton design pattern. It's more of a pseudo-singleton. It's a combination of Registry (`self::register()`) and [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) (`self::getModel()`).

Comment: okay thanks. Need to ask what does this do then `code`Mage::getSingleton('customer/session') does?

Comment: Like I said. It gives you an instance of the model with alias `customer/session` (most probably `Mage_Customer_Model_Session`), and the same instance every time. in one request.

Answer (score 2):

Per your comment, the following code

```
$object = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
```

Instantiates the `customer/session` model as a singleton in Magento.  It's the equivalent to doing something like this in plain old PHP

```
$object = new Mage_Customer_Model_Session;
```

with the added benefits that calls to `getSingleton` will **always** return the same object.  For example, in the following fake mini-program.

```
function one()
{
    $object_1 = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
}

function two()
{
    $object_2 = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
}

one();
two();
```

the variable `$object_1` and `$object_2` are the **same** object.

Answer (score -1):

Its singleton implementation using Registry for Model ( classes ) !